# Composer freezes at random moments

Tags: crash, composer-php

I tried to install Nette framework (by `composer create-project nette/sandbox nette-blog`, as proposed [here](http://doc.nette.org/en/2.2/quickstart/getting-started)) through Composer, but the installation stopped in half. There was no more activity in the process php.exe (I made sure it corresponds to Composer in this case) and command line's state didn't change for hours. Later installs ended somewhat earlier in a similar manner. I tried `composer diagnose` and it reports OK for everything - but only in about one third of the times, when it doesn't end the same way as the project creation. I re-installed Composer, but the problems remained. I suspected Nette of damaging Composer somehow, so I re-installed Composer once more and ran `composer-diagnose` without trying to install Nette - and the problem is still there.

So what's the cause of this mysterious freezing, and how to solve it?

I installed Composer through the windows installer, on Windows 7.